# Read excel file in java without using any jars

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, java-9, java-10

I have a requirement to read excel file in java without using any third party library jar like POI,JEXCEL .I don't know exactly can spring support for same? Please suggest if you know something.

Thanks in advance

Using POI I have done but read without using any jar

```
 public static void readFromExcel(String file) throws IOException{
        HSSFWorkbook myExcelBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
        HSSFSheet myExcelSheet = myExcelBook.getSheet("Birthdays");
        HSSFRow row = myExcelSheet.getRow(0);

        if(row.getCell(0).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
            String name = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println("name : " + name);
        }
```

Comment: it is just a file, use `FileInputStream` to read it... but you will need to know its format to parse it

Comment: XLSX is a ZIP file containing XML files. You can parse that with builtin features, if you read the specification and implement it. I don’t know what “can spring support for same” is supposed to mean, but when you are not allowed to use 3rd party libraries, it likely doesn’t matter *which* 3rd party library, including Spring related libraries…

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use a 3rd party JAR or library you will need to write a parser to read the document into your data classes.

I would advise you to take a look at the [file format specification for Microsoft Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-offfflp/8aea05e3-8c1e-4a9a-9614-31f71e679456). You will need to understand this to build a reliable parser.

It would be much easier to just use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and see if the requirements can be changed to allow it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for your response.could you give some reference code how to build parser without using any jar or library.

Comment: @Rajendra If you are going to reinvent the wheel, reinvent the wheel. Don't ask someone to reinvent the wheel for you.